# google apps script conditional if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, conditional-statements

I'm fairly new to GAS but learning fast.  Thanks in advance for any help you can offer on this!!

I need to be able to send an email to two different email addresses based on the first characters of my last name field.  So, if the first character of var last is A - L, send the email to this person, otherwise, if the first character is M - Z, send to this other person.  How would I create a conditional if statement for this?  My current script which currently sends all email to the same address is as follows:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

var timestamp = e.values[0];
var last = e.values[3];
var first = e.values[4];
var employment_status = e.values[5];
var unemployed_date = e.values[6];
var employment_type = e.values[7];
var employer_name = e.values[8];
var employer_address = e.values[9];
var employment_begin = e.values[10];
var comments = e.values[11];

var email = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
var subject = "Employment Update Received";

var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
+ "<P>Dear " + first + " " + last + ","
etc. etc.
+ "</HTML></BODY>";

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JonnyJS is on the right track. I used just regular expressions. Regex literals are wrapped in  `/ /` and options occur after the last `/`. I usually use [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com) to test regular expressions for GAS. You can find more information about JS Regex on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Most notably, the [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Ftest) function that I use below.

---

Here's the regex I used:

`^` Starts of string

`[A-L]` Any letter A-L

`.*` Any character, 0 or more times

`$` End of String

`i` Option for case insensitive regex

---

Here is a snippet for you to use.

```
var last = e.values[3].trim(); // Remove any leading spaces to be safe
var email = "Catch-Other-Names@mydomain.com";

var reAtoL = /^[A-L].*$/i;
var reMtoZ = /^[M-Z].*$/i;

if (reAtoL.test(last)) {
  email = "A-to-L-Recipient@mydomain.com";

} else if (reMtoZ.test(last)) {
  email = "M-to-Z-Recipient@mydomain.com";
}

// If both fail, then it's going to the Catch Other Names

Mail.sendEmail(email, subject, "", {htmlBody:message});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  This is working great!  And I appreciate the link to RegexPal.

Answer (score 0):

You havent been really clear but i hope i got what you meant.

I solve it by using two built in js stuff.

1. we cut the string to the first latter.
2. we matching the cutted part to regular expression.

Consider view that on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4dDfZ/)

lets write the markup first:

```
<form>
<input name="last" type="text"/></form>
<br><br>
<div id="status">
</div>
```

now some JS:

```
var rel = new RegExp("[a-l A-L]");
var rez = new RegExp("[m-z M-Z]");
$("form input").on("change",function(e){
    vall = $("form input").val().substr(0,1);
    console.log(vall);
    if (rel.exec(vall)) {
        $("#status").text("We Got a winner! the last name starts with letter from a-l");
    }
    else if (rez.exec(vall)) {
         $("#status").text("Hodey! the last name starts with letter from m-z");
    }
    else {
        $("#status").text("Well, Nothing cool here.");
    }
});
```

as you can see im using jquery to prettify things.
if you still in trouble please write in comments.

Comment: JohnnyJS, thank you for your help.  The if/else statements will help.  Now I just need to know the JS that will utilize the e.value "last".  You showed me how to do it in an html form, but how do I make it so that my function analyzes the e.value "last" and assigns a different email address (var email) depending on the result of the if/else condition?  In other words, if var last begins a-l, then var email = john@gmail.com else if var last begins m-z, then var email = bob@gmail.com.  Sorry for the amateur way of saying this.  I hope it's clear.